# Explicit copy constructor of a parameter passed via std::async

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, copy-constructor, explicit, stdasync

In the following program `foo` function is executed asynchronously and its argument of type `A` is copied inside `async` by value:

```
#include <future>

struct A {
    A() = default;
    explicit A(const A &) = default;
};

void foo(const A &) {}

int main() {
    auto f = std::async(std::launch::async, foo, A{});
}
```

Despite copy-constructor of `A` is explicit, the program is accepted in the latest MSVC and in libstdc++ from GCC 10. But starting from GCC 11 the program is rejected with the

```
error: could not convert '{std::forward<void (&)(const A&)>((* & __args#0)), std::forward<A>((* & __args#1))}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'std::tuple<void (*)(const A&), A>'
 1693 |           _M_fn{{std::forward<_Args>(__args)...}}
```

Online demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/r3PsoaxT7

Is GCC 11 more correct here or it is a regression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the post-C++20 draft (https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/futures.async) there is a "*Mandates:*" clause which effectively only requires `std::is_move_constructible_v<A>` to be satisfied. This tests whether a declaration of the form

```
A a(std::declval<A&&>());
```

would be well-formed, which it is even with `explicit` on the constructor. Therefore the "*Mandates:*"-clause is satisfied. (If it was not, the program would be ill-formed.)

However there is also a "*Precondition:*" clause effectively requiring `A` to be *Cpp17MoveConstructible*. This library concept has the effective requirement that

```
A a = rv;
```

where `rv` is a rvalue of type `A` (see https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/library#tab:cpp17.moveconstructible), is well-formed. This is not the case here, since this is copy-initialization which doesn't consider `explicit` constructors. Theferore the "*Precondition:*" clause is not satisfied, which causes the program to have *undefined behavior*.

As a result both behaviors are conforming.

---

However, in the current draft the precondition has been removed with resolution of [LWG issue 3476](https://wg21.link/lwg3476) ([draft commit](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/commit/6b3c8a891fb6aaadb97a0d434f934b15299fc79a)) and I don't see anything else that would forbid the type from being usable as an argument to `std::async`. The arguments are now specified to be constructed with `auto(/*...*/)` which does consider explicit constructors. The resolution of the mentioned issue explicitly says that no other copy/move should be allowed either.

Comment: Thanks, GCC bug reported: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=106695